# Simulating actor inheritance in Elixir

Tags: inheritance, elixir, actor

A bunch of my colleagues and I are designing a new programming language, and we're considering Elixir as the target language. The thing is though, that the language is largely based on Scala's syntax and semantics, which means it needs to allow inheritance in some way or another.

Rather than classes however, the idea is to use actors in their place, but this raises an interesting problem: How do you simulate class-like inheritance using Elixir's functions? Or in other words, is it possible to somehow get one function to inherit another function's `receiver` patterns?

A-la this:

```
def io_port do
  receive do
    {:transmit, data} -> # do stuff with data
    {:receive, data} -> # do other stuff with data
  end
end

def thunderbolt, extends: io_port do
  receive do # also accepts all the same messages io_port does
    {:display, data} -> # same story again
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look at Elixir's protocols. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html

Comment: Additionally check out Elixir's `use` macro: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#use.  It feels a lot like inheritance and/or mix-ins from Ruby. Not to mention you may look at the implementation of the `use` macro and get some ideas for implementing your own macro(s) that give you the language feature you desire.

Comment: I was also going to recommend the `use` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Elixir doesn't allow You to insert macros at the matching level like:

```
receive do
  macro1()
  macro2()
end
```

So You can't really do dynamic matching on messages.
But You could use OTP components to make something similar to inheritance
like:

```
defmodule IOPort do
  use Actor

  defmacro receiver do
    quote do
      def handle_call({:transmit, data}), do: # do stuff with data
     end
  end
end
```

and

```
defmodule Thunderbolt do
  use Actor, extend: IOPort

  defmacro receiver do
    quote do
      def handle_call({:display, data}), do: # do stuff with data
     end
  end
end
```

And write something like

```
defmodule Actor

  defmacro __using__([]) do
    __MODULE__.receiver
  end

  defmacro __using__([extends: mod]) do
    mod.receiver
    __MODULE__.receiver
  end

end
```

Of course it's just a concept, not really tested. But it could work like that with GenServer, plus using OTP would save You a lot of reinventing the wheel

PS. 
PM me about this programming language of yours. If it's worth a while I'd gladly help

Comment: I'll write you about it once I've been through my exam. So far it's still a student project